# How to set a maximum number displayed in achartengine library?

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using the achartengine library which is a pretty cool stuff but I can't find how to set a "maximum number lenght" displayed. For instance, when the value is like: "60000", I would like to display something like this: "60" or "60k".

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cjld.png]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set max limit for y or x axis values

```
  mRenderer.setYAxisMax(5000);
```

But for length of numbers you have to write some logic like

```
   int x;
    if(x>100)
    { x= x/10;}
    if(x>1000)
    { x= x/100;}
```

etc.

Comment: This is exactly the last thing I would do. Is there another way to do this ?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: Well thanks for you answer. Hope that someday, the achartengine's team will add this kind of feature.